# I need to getImageViewResource() in android

Tags: android, imageview

I am setting the resource of an image view programatically:

```
remoteViews.setImageViewResource(R.id.imageView, R.drawable.awake);
```

I am switching between two images, and I would like to know the current imageview value before I switch, to make my app perform more efficiently.

The ideal function call would be:

```
remoteViews.getImageViewResource(R.id.imageView);
```

Answer (score 0):

As there is no API for your need, try [SparseIntArray](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/SparseIntArray.html) to map Drawable IDs to View IDs (and get the Drawable for the specific View before assigning a new one).